# Smartmenus submenu position

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this http://vadikom.github.io/smartmenus/src/demo/bootstrap-navbar.html for my long dropdown menus. 
But how to make the submenus dropdown in the same top as the parents like this image below?
[image]

This the js code I've add but nothing happen. Thanks for your help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
     $('#main-menu').smartmenus({
        subMenusSubOffsetX: 5,
        subMenusSubOffsetY: 20
     });
   });
</script>
```

This is some part for html code

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="navbar-left">
            <a href="#" onClick="loadData();">Home</a>                        
        </li>
        <li class="navbar-left">
            <a href="#">Menu</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="main-menu">
                <li class=" row search-box">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input class="form-control search" id="search-criteria" type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="menu" href="#">This submenu level 2<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 4</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Menu item 5</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 5</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 6</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 7</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 8</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 9</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 10</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 11</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 12</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 13</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 14</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 15</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 16</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 17</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 18</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 19</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 20</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 5</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 6</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 7</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 8</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 9</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 10</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 11</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 12</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 13</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 14</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 15</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 16</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 17</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 18</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 19</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 20</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 5</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 6</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 7</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 8</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 9</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 10</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 11</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 12</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 13</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 14</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 15</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 16</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 17</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 18</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 19</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 20</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 6</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 7</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 8</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 9</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 10</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 11</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 12</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 13</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 14</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 15</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 16</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 17</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 18</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 19</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu item 20</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="menu" href="#">Another Link<span class="caret"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is it like you want, the "Menu item 1" to appear on the same position as of "A long sub menu" (parent), rather that showing at the top ?

Comment: I want the submenu in level 2 or 3 is showing below the navbar like the parent. In that image is the result I want.

Comment: Then provide us the HTML part / Jsfiddle of your current code.

Comment: Now I'd already give the html code. My current code have a long dropdown in every level, so I just add some example like that. Thanks.